# While using DVWP(in Sharepoint 2010) the 'Person or Group' column is not showing the profile picture of the person

Tags: 2010, data-view-web-part

I have a custom list in SharePoint 2010, in which i have a column of type 'People or Group'.
When i am displaying the content of this list using a DVWP, i expect the picture/image of each person to be displayed along with the other data. But, i can't see the picture of the person.

Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look into the below links for the same.

http://www.glynblogs.com/2010/11/displaying-a-users-picture-in-the-data-view-web-part.html

http://www.glynblogs.com/2010/11/display-a-users-picture-in-the-content-query-web-part.html